# System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: exception, memory-management, c#-3.0, ms-word, office-interop

I get the following exception when I try to "find and replace" in a Word 2007 working on Windows Vista or Windows 7.

> System.AccessViolationException:
>   Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt.    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find.Execute(Object&
>   FindText, Object& MatchCase, Object&
>   MatchWholeWord, Object&
>   MatchWildcards, Object&
>   MatchSoundsLike, Object&
>   MatchAllWordForms, Object& Forward,
>   Object& Wrap, Object& Format, Object&
>   ReplaceWith, Object& Replace, Object&
>   MatchKashida, Object& MatchDiacritics,
>   Object& MatchAlefHamza, Object&
>   MatchControl)

Is there any solution for this ?

Iam using .NET3.5 C#.

**********CODE****************

```
public static Application Open(string fileName)
{
    object fileNameAsObject = (object)fileName;
    Application wordApplication;            
    wordApplication = new Application();
    object readnly = false;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    wordApplication.Documents.Open(
        ref fileNameAsObject, ref missing, ref readnly, 
        ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
        ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
        ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
        ref missing
    );

    return wordApplication;             
}
```

---

```
private static void ReplaceObject(
    ref Application wordApplication, 
    object ObjectTobeReplaced, object NewObject)
{
    // ++++++++Find Replace options Starts++++++

object findtext = ObjectTobeReplaced;
    object findreplacement = NewObject;
    object findforward = true;
    object findformat = false;
    object findwrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
    object findmatchcase = false;
    object findmatchwholeword = false;
    object findmatchwildcards = false;
    object findmatchsoundslike = false;
    object findmatchallwordforms = false;
    object replace = 2; //find = 1; replace = 2
    object nevim = false;
    Range range = wordApplication.ActiveDocument.Content;
    range.Find.Execute(
        ref findtext, ref findmatchcase, ref findmatchwholeword, 
        ref findmatchwildcards,ref findmatchsoundslike, 
        ref findmatchallwordforms, ref findforward, ref findwrap,
        ref findformat, ref findreplacement, ref replace, 
        ref nevim, ref nevim, ref nevim, ref nevim
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was fixed after reinstalling Office :)...  But still dont know what caused the issue

Answer (score 1):

This is next to impossible to answer without you showing any code you have.

A (wild) guess would be that you supply some class/structure when interoping with Word that is not initialized and Word then tries to access the uninitialized memory.